# WooCommerce, If Custom Meta Checkbox Checked, Return Product As "Sold Out"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

having a bit of trouble with WooCommerce, basically on the store I am working on there will need to be an option to display a "Call to Order" message instead of showing the default "Add to Cart" form or "Sold Out" message.

I have kind of achieved this by adding a custom metabox checkbox in the product edit back-end, and an if statement in the single product add to cart template, the only problem is all this does is hide the add to cart form and the product can still be added like so "http://localhost/wordpress/woocommerce/shop/?add-to-cart=14" so its not exactly full-proof.

What I am looking for is to somehow make the product out of stock when the custom checkbox is checked, I was looking in the WooCommerce plugin admin back-end files and this is used a lot:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock' );
```

So I thought it would be as easy this in functons.php:

```
global $post;
if ($meta_box = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_test_checkbox", true) ) :
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock' );
endif;
```

Turns out its not. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me crazy.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To hide the items out of stock button:

```
    if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
        function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
            global $product;
            if (!$product->is_in_stock()) return;
            woocommerce_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
        }
    }
```

To change the Add To Cart button:

```
// Change the "Add to Cart" button on the single product page.
    function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        return __('My Button Text', 'woocommerce'); 
    }

    add_filter('single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text');
```

Or, if you would specifically like to modify the template structure:

Create a folder called `/woocommerce` in your theme's directory > create another folder inside of this called `/loop` and place the `add-to-cart.php` file inside.  Then modify line 17

from:

```
<p class="out-of-stock" ><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></p>
```

to:

```
<p class="out-of-stock" ><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Out of Stock', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any filters in the product class for tweaking the stock quantities or status... probably as this kind of defeats the purpose of stock management.

So we can do 1 of 2 things. (I don't think we need both, but who knows.) Anyway, first we could add some custom validation to prevent the item from ever being added to the cart.

```
/*
 * Validate when adding to cart
 * @param bool $passed
 * @param int $product_id
 * @param int $quantity
 * @return bool
 */
function so_12959338_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $qty ){

    if( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $product_id, '_cmb_test_checkbox', true ) ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s cannot be added to the cart because of reasons.', 'my-plugin-textdomain' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_12959338_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
```

Or we could prevent it from being added to the cart AND prevent the add to cart buttons from even displaying, by making the product not purchasable.

Now in both my code blocks, I wasn't sure what value you were saving with your checkbox. WooCommerce uses "yes" and "no" for booleans, so that's what my code represents. Adapt as needed.

```
/*
 * Make the item non-purchasable
 * @param bool $purchasable
 * @param obj $product
 * @return bool
 */
function so_12959338_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){

    if( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $product->id, '_cmb_test_checkbox', true ) ){
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    return $purchasable;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'so_12959338_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```